# Multisig on js extension

Tags: polkadot-js-extension, multisig

I created a multisig account on Polkadot.js. The multisig does not populate in the extension. I use firefox. I want to use the multisig with polkaswap. How do i get my multisig account to appear on my extension? How can I use it with polkaswap?

Comment: Please [provide steps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check this guide on the Polkadot Support Page: [How to Create and Use a Multisig Account](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000181826-how-to-create-and-use-a-multisig-account)